# Why is my Flutter App not getting the updated data in Firebase Realtime Database?

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Currently, I am working on a flutter project that uses Realtime Database in Firebase. This app has an update functionality for the details of the user. I have successfully implemented the updating functionality as it is being stored in the database right after the update. However, when I go back to the View Profile Page, the details that are being displayed are not yet updated. I need to go to some other tab first and then go back to the View Profile page where the updated data will then be loaded. Why there are delays, shouldn't it be real-time, once I updated the data? Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks!

**Here is my code for displaying the current user's information:**

```
static void readCurrentOnlineUserInfo() async
  {

    final FirebaseAuth fAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    User? currentFirebaseUser;

    currentFirebaseUser = fAuth.currentUser;

    DatabaseReference userRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance
        .ref()
        .child("passengers")
        .child(currentFirebaseUser!.uid);

    userRef.once().then((snap)
    {
      if(snap.snapshot.value != null)
      {
        userModelCurrentInfo = UserModel.fromSnapshot(snap.snapshot);
        print("name" + userModelCurrentInfo!.first_name.toString());
        print("username" + userModelCurrentInfo!.username.toString());
      }
    });
  }
```

**On the other hand, this is the code that I am using for displaying the data into my app:**

```
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';

class UserModel
{
  String? first_name;
  String? last_name;
  String? id;
  String? email;
  String? username;
  String? password;
  String? phoneNum;

  UserModel({this.first_name, this.last_name, this.id, this.email, this.username, this.password, this.phoneNum});

  UserModel.fromSnapshot(DataSnapshot snap)
  {
    first_name = (snap.value as dynamic)["first_name"];
    last_name = (snap.value as dynamic)["last_name"];
    id = snap.key;
    email = (snap.value as dynamic)["email"];
    username = (snap.value as dynamic)["username"];
    password = (snap.value as dynamic)["password"];
    phoneNum = (snap.value as dynamic)["phoneNum"];
  }
}
```

**I display the above information in widgets like this:**

```
UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Color(0xFFFED90F),
                ),
                accountName: new Text(userCurrentModelInfo!.first_name,
                  style: TextStyle( color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 15,
                    fontFamily: "Montserrat",
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,),
                ),
```

Comment: can you show a widget with the Text(userModelCurrentInfo!.username!) ? Is this a statefulWidget ? how the userModelCurrentInfo is instanced ?

Comment: @EricMartin yes it is in a stateful widget.

Comment: What doyou mean by show a widget?

Comment: The userModelCurrentInfo is instanced in the first block of codes I have provided.

Comment: Sorry i did not read correctly. Your readCurrentOnlineUserInfo method is called in the build method of your drawer ?

Comment: @EricMartin my drawer is not in a separate file, it is also in my main page. I called it inside my initState

Comment: OK,i can't help without your main page code. Maybe the initState is not the good location or maybe you miss a setState.

Comment: Where can I share my main page code, so you can check it? Its to long I can't post it here. @EricMartin

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249319/flutter-real-time-db

Comment: @EricMartin I have attached here my main page code. Maybe you can check it as it will be a very big help. Thanks. https://github.com/kryzlerahne/MainPage.git

Comment: @EricMartin I don't have much reputation to chat on the room. :(

Answer (score 0):

Don't Use `Future Builder` To get Real-time updates to use `stream builder` to get a real-time update

that's why you get the data when you go to another screen and come back when you use stream builder it always checks there is new data in the DB and it shows the new data

Comment: Hi! How do I implement that? What will I need to change?

Comment: in your UI file change Future Builder to Stream Builder

Comment: In my main page, I searched the word Future, but there is only one method that uses Future builder, which is the function for drawing polyline in the map. I am not quite sure if that's what you meant because I am not familiar with it.

Comment: Can you help me correct my codes, I can share you the file because Im realy confused.

Comment: sure please share it on GitHub or update this question

Comment: https://github.com/kryzlerahne/MainPage.git Here is my main page, any help will be much appreciated, if you need any more file let me know thanks.

Comment: can you add all of your files to GitHub and share it then I can clone it to fix this

Comment: first, run flutter clean after that go to the project folder and zip it then upload it to the drive

Comment: @annyeongk your API_KEY (firebase, maps, etc) are in your project. You don't have to share.

Comment: @EricMartin have you seen the project? Which part should I edit to fix my problem? Please help :( I am really confused

Comment: i checked your project but you i didn't use any of builders ?

Comment: yes, thats why i dont know how to fix my problem. please help? @MrShakila

Comment: your code is a little bit not organized but you need to create a StreamBuider function where you need to update your info it will fix your issue I cant tell where exactly sorry

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you use `once`, which reads the data once (hence its name).

If you want to get updated about changes to the data, use `onValue` as shown in the documentation on [reading data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#read_data). That also means you'll have to either store the data from the database in the state of your widget, or use a `StreamBuilder` to display it (since `onValue` returns a `Stream`).

For an example of using a `StreamBuilder` to display realtime updates from Firebase's other database, have a look at the second code snippet in this documentation on [listening for realtime updates](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#dart). Where that uses `FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').snapshots();`, you'll want to use your `onValue`.

Comment: Hi! I have shared my code in my main page, can you consider checking it, I am really confused which part I need to change. Hope you can check, thanks!

Comment: Also, I am using Real time Database in Firebase

Comment: https://github.com/kryzlerahne/MainPage.git

Comment: The Firestore link in my answer is just an easy example of how to use a stream builder. As said, you'll need to replace the `snapshots()` stream in there with the `onValue` stream that you get from Realtime Database.